# File Reading In C with a specific format

Tags: c

I wanted read a text file in **C** and I want to perform search on this file. This is the content of the text file:

(**EDIT**: The original format looks a bit different as there are no newlines in the file. It has been reformatted to remove the whitespace between the text strings and filtered through a multicolumn program for a 80col screen.)

```
^%1~3~31225~2999              ^%1~8~33983~5304
~MAC100                      ~MAC100
~RAJU                        ~LATHA CHERIAN
CR                           ~ELIM VILLA
~CHEMPOLA                    ~1
~VT : 2999                   ~9847569922
~9847569922                  ~32166
~29408                       ~Message for bill gro~1960.0
~Message for bill gro~750.0  ~160.0
~250.0                       ~0.0
~0.0                         ~1~scheme name
~1~scheme name               ~0
~0                           ~June
~June                        ~VA019_95784~-
~VA019_93159~-               ~0.0
~0.0                         ~0~amc date 1~amc date 2~990
~1~amc date 1~amc date 2~990 ~15.0
~15.0                        ~150.0
~150.0                       ~narration
~narration                   ^%1~9~31588~3235
^%1~5~30882~2496             ~MAC100
~MAC100                      ~BABU
~VISWAMPARAN T. P.           ~NADUMPARMBIL
~THALAKOTTUCHALIL            ~0
~C 4771                      ~9847569922
~9847569922                  ~29771
~29065                       ~Message for bill gro~3304.0
~Message for bill gro~4320.0 ~160.0
~160.0                       ~0.0
~0.0                         ~1~scheme name
~1~scheme name               ~0
~0                           ~June
~June                        ~VA019_93516~-
~VA019_92833~-               ~0.0
~0.0                         ~0~amc date 1~amc date 2~990
~0~amc date 1~amc date 2~990 ~15.0
~15.0                        ~150.0
~150.0                       ~narration
~narration                   ^?
```

This is database in format of billing system. I want to do a generic search function this file based on the name and the id (which is the `^%1~9~**31588**~3235`,     `here 31588` like that). This is file of records. Each record are begin with `^%1.~` the `~` is used to separate column values of each record. The first and last characters are not needed (`^%1` in of each records and `^?` at last of the file).  Please help me to do this.

Comment: Are you sure this is a pure text file? Please describe your record format. Hmm with c, ok.

Comment: What you want here is a simple text reader in C that reads in your columns into a record structure. It would help if we know what types the records have. For example INTEGER, FLOAT, STRING, whatever. And are there forbidden characters in STRINGS, like `%` and `^` ?

Comment: %1~3~31225~2999        ~MAC100      ~RAJU     CR             ~CHEMPOLA            ~VT : 2999           ~9847569922          ~29408               ~Message for bill gro~750.0     ~250.0     ~0.0       ~1~scheme name         ~0         ~June      ~VA019_93159~-         ~0.0       ~1~amc date 1~amc date 2~990       ~15.0      ~150.0     ~narration                                         this my actual format of file.This is a 2 record in my file.there is no such newline charectors.record are seperated by the ^%1

Answer (score 1):

You first should define (or understand) *precisely* your input format (what are the possible & forbidden characters), perhaps using some EBNF notation.

Then you could process your input line by line (using `fgets` or `getline`) and parse each line individually (using `sscanf` or `strtol` and extra manual parsing)

Answer (score 0):

Read Line by Line using fgets(), and then tokenize using strtok on the basis "~". hope that works